# How to Add Values to a Java DB (Derby) Database from a Servlet

Tags: java, database, servlets

How would I add a value to the Java DB database from a servlet?

Comment: Ask the proper question ..... Add code with question also

Answer (score 1):

- open database
- insert data
- close database

if you post a vague question, you get a vague answer.
Extra tip: learn JPA or JDBC